# How to increment numbers using Event Listeners and Widget Viewer in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, event-handling, widget

I'm writing a WidgetViewer GUI where when the "go up/up" button is pushed, a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) is generated and added to the left label, and another random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) is generated and added to the right label.

The widgets required are: a button labeled "go up/up", a label initialized to 0 (left label), and a label initialized to 0 (right label).

This is what I have so far:

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.Jbutton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
   
    public class UpDown {
           private JLabel jleft;
           private JLabel jright;
           
           public UpDown() {
                  WidgetViewer wv = new WidgetViewer();
                  jleft = new JLabel("0");
                  jright = new JLabel("0");
                   
                  JButton upUp = new JButton("go up/up");
                  upUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                              String lval = jleft.getText();
                              int newlVal = Integer.parseInt(lval) + 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (10));
                              jleft.setText(String.valueOf(newlVal));
                              String rval = jright.getText();
                              int newrVal = Integer.parseInt(rval) + 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (10));
                              jleft.setText(String.valueOf(newrVal));
                        }
                  });
      }
```

However, when I run this and when I click the button, it only shows a new number each time without adding to it. How can I make it increment each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

left value is processed correcty, the right value is calculated correctly too ... but stored in the ui-element of the left value ...

```
jleft.setText(String.valueOf(newrVal));
```

=> overwriting the just previously correct left value, resetting it. just replace with

```
jright.setText(String.valueOf(newrVal));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm a little confused, though. Isn't this what I already have in my code?

Comment: read your code carefully, last line of your eventhandler, there is jleft instead of jright ...

Comment: "String rval = jright.getText();" // => correct, get the old right value


"int newrVal = Integer.parseInt(rval) + 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (10));"  // => correct, construct the new value


"jleft.setText(String.valueOf(newrVal));" // => wrong. the new rightvalue is put into jleft instead of jright

Comment: btw ... using confusing abbrevations might save you a few seconds while typing ... but they will get/trick  you later. use really speaking parameter names, enabling other developers to read your code ...  "jLabelLeft.setText(String.valueOf(newRightValue));" would have been obviously wrong at first glance ...

Comment: Oh, gotcha! I didn't see that mistake. Thank you so much for your help, and I will take your advice with my variable names. I do find myself getting confused and trying to keep it as short as possible when it's actually better to be detailed to be safe